# Change ImageView picture inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

quick question since I can't figure it out by myself.

First off, I don't want to come out as a begger so I will tell you what I DO know.

This piece of code works great:

```
package com.edip.splashwallpaper;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;
    Switch mSwitch;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//                getImage();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "AlarmReceiver Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        setAlarmManager(); //TODO zbog ovog mi se gasi AlarmManager. FIX IT!

    }

    private void setAlarmManager(){
        AlarmManager alrm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        final String IF_ACTION = "com.edip.splashwallpaper.AlarmReceiver";
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(IF_ACTION);
        AlarmReceiver mReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
        Intent i2 = new Intent(IF_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, i2, 0);
        alrm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 5000, 60000, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void getImage() {

        String mRandomKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); //Generates random string

        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/1920x1080/")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder)
                .stableKey(mRandomKey) //new key is new picture
                .into(mImageView);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            }
        }, 5000); //adding 5 sec delay

    }

    public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);

            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "New Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to set Wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Code is running without error and background image is being changed every XY minutes. **Problem is**, the `BroadcastReceiver` class is inside `MainActivity` class and if the user **cleans** "recent apps" (or any other type of memory cleaning, i.e. `CleanMaster`) - **`AlarmManager` Stops**.

Now, I tried to make `BroadcastReceiver` class separately and tested it with `Toast`, and it works - `AlarmManager` is not stopped. **Problem is**, I get `NullPointerException` when calling **`getImage()`** function from `MainActivity`. My guess is, `BroadcastReceiver` can't update `ImageView` of another `Activity`.

I also tried to put `getImage()` function in `BroadcastReceiver`, but then again, I can't set up `findViewById(R.id.imageView)` in it.

The same thing goes for Service class. `Toast` works, but can't run `getImage()` function.

At this point, I really don't know what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: `if the user cleans "recent apps" (or any other type of memory cleaning, i.e. CleanMaster) - AlarmManager Stops` then of course get NPE error because Activity is not running means `mImageView` is `null` and also  `MainActivity.this` will give a invalid Context error

Comment: ok now i'm off the work so I can build minimal example ... and here is a smallest way for doing this (without any library and should work on ever device with API > 5 ... https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/be80f168797517291c81

Comment: @Selvin It amazes me how you managed to come up with that 5min after I posted the question, while I struggled with it for three days.
I appreciate the code, I learned some new stuff from it.
P.S. May I use it and add some of my code to it? Its cleaner than mine and all I actually needed is InputStream to make my own code work. :)

Thank you,

Comment: As you can see it has Apache 2 license, so yes you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Selvin for helping me out. The question is now answered.